# Hover state moves my h2 around in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, hover

I am currently working on a test page to work out a php function and came across a very odd bug.

When you hover over the nav items with the name link 1, link 2, link 3 the h2 that is below the header seems to jump up and down.

The hover state is targeting a specific fontawesome class and in no way targets the h2.

The hover state styles:

```
ul.mainNav > li a:hover .fa-caret-square-o-up {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

The text "Search by zip-code" is the h2 element.

Here is a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jXEwj/show/)

How can I go about to fix this issue and if anyone knows why this is happening then please let me know. :]

Comment: This works well for me too. Please try to refresh your cache and re-open chrome. Can't reproduce the problem, sorry. Maybe you can set the weird default margin-top value of the h2 manually to a whole number(By the moment: margin-top: 12.4499998092651px)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.wrapper` class has `position:relative`.

Disabling that solves the problem but may break other layout.

Comment: Sadly I do need `position: relative;` on the wrapper but is this just a bug? When I changed my layout around on this http://healthbenefitsohio.com/zip-code-test/ it also seemed to fix it.

Comment: You only need `position` relative because you are using absolute positioning on the logo. Try reforming the HTML of the header using floats or inline block unless there is something else going on. As to whether there is another solution, I don't know....because I don't know what is actually causing the problem.

Comment: I need it for other elements besides the logo, i use the wrapper in each main section. Since I added more structure it removed the problem, just a weird bug I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have changed the demo in your original post or the comment in Paulie_D's answer but when I view the pages, I do not see the elements moving. I am using Google chrome Version 32.0.1700.72 m. Are you using a current version?

Comment: I did not edit the demo and the version I am running is, Version 32.0.1700.76 which is slightly newer then your version.

Comment: I just updated my chrome browser and still don't see the issue. I even tried firefox (v26.0) and it worked correctly. I do not see the text "Search by zip-code" move when hovering over the Link 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Hmm very strange because it is still doing it for me. Firefox does not display it happening, I'm on windows currently.

Comment: I agree it is strange. I'm on windows 7 and a large resolution 1600x1200. I've noticed this "jumping" effect before when the scroll bar appears in the browser but that isn't the case here.

Comment: Maybe you can see it here, http://healthbenefitsohio.com/zip-code-test/. Watch as the two columns below the header seem to twitch between each other.

Comment: That worked correctly for me again too... Are you loading some search results first and then hovering? Maybe someone else can test this too.. maybe I'm the odd ball haha.

Comment: I am not, currently the site is not set up to any database. It must just be a new bug with a new version of chrome.